# Optional Appears in the result

Tags: swift, option-type

I am currently learning swift and I wrote the following silly code but the result shows like this : "The monster is Optional("sihso") when the hero is at level 2". i don't know why there is the word optional there.

```
var level = 2
var mons = [1 : "SHhi", 2 : "sihso", 3 : "shssh"]
var monster = mons [level]
print("The monster is \(monster)" + " when the hero is at level \(level)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word `Optional` is there because `monster` has the implicit type `String?`, an optional string.

When dictionary's are queried for the value at a specific key, they return an optional type.  A value may or may not exist for a given key.  If it doesn't exist, it returns `nil`.

So, we have to check to be sure we got a value out.

```
let level = 2
let mons = [1 : "SHhi", 2 : "sihso", 3 : "shssh"]
if let monster = mons[level] {
    print("The monster is \(monster) when the hero is at level \(level)")
}
```

As a note, *if* `mons` didn't have a value for the key we passed it, nothing would print at all (which is most likely what we want).

If we want to print either way, the best approach is probably to use the `nil`-coalescing operator (`??`):

```
let level = 2
let mons = [1 : "SHhi", 2 : "sihso", 3 : "shssh"]
var monster = mons[level] ?? "unknown"
print("The monster is \(monster) when the hero is at level \(level)")
```

Now, any time `mons[level]` would return `nil`, `monster` will instead be equal to `"unknown"`, and the message will print every time (and never print `Optional()` with it).